# PJSIP : Video Call In Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, pjsip, callkit

I am working on PJSIP. Two ways Video and Audio call are working fine but the issue is when app is in background and I made a new Incoming call, The callKit is showing new incoming call and I picked up the call. Then app moves from background to foreground but video is not showing and audio is working at that time. If I made a call in foreground then video is showing at both end.
Please find below the logs :

```
15:48:19.251 ios_opengl_dev  .......Failed to initialize iOS OpenGL because we are in background

15:48:19.251     vid_port.c  .......Closing OpenGL renderer..

15:48:19.319    pjsua_vid.c  .......Window 0: destroying..

15:48:19.319  pjsua_media.c  ....pjsua_vid_channel_update() failed for call_id 0 media 1: video subsystem not initialized (PJMEDIA_EVID_INIT)

15:48:19.319  pjsua_media.c  ....Error updating media call00:1: video subsystem not initialized (PJMEDIA_EVID_INIT)

15:48:19.319    pjsua_app.c  ...Call 0 media 0 [type=audio], status is Active

15:48:19.319    pjsua_aud.c  ...Conf connect: 3 --> 0

15:48:19.319    pjsua_app.c  ....Turning sound device ON

15:48:19.319   conference.c  ....Port 3 (sip:linchpin@192.168.1.7) transmitting to port 0 (Master/sound)

15:48:19.319    pjsua_aud.c  ...Conf connect: 0 --> 3

15:48:19.319   conference.c  ....Port 0 (Master/sound) transmitting to port 3 (sip:linchpin@192.168.1.7)

15:48:19.319    pjsua_app.c  ...Call 0 media 1 [type=video], status is Error

15:48:19.319    pjsua_app.c  ...Just rejected incoming video offer on call 0, use "vid call enable 1" or "vid call add" to enable video!
```

Comment: Hi Ved Rauniyar, how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add some delay in answering the call it will work as sometimes PJSIP is taking time to initiate the camera.